# Como obtener el valor de un atributo de una relacion con un camino string en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-8, reflection

tengo una duda, tengo una tabla la cual almacena variables de mi sistema que el usuario puede seleccionar y poner en sus documentos (Tipo StackOverflow), cuando un documento se guarda en el sistema se guarda con las claves de las variables por ejemplo `{NombreUsuario}` y su valor es `{'name'}` y si quiero acceder a un atributo de una relación lo guardo así `{'iDEmpresa'}` y su valor es `{'empresa->id'}` el primer ejemplo lo obtengo fácilmente con reflexiones de esta manera:

```
function obtenerAtributo($objeto, $camino) {
$parts = explode('->', $camino);
$valor = $objeto;

foreach ($parts as $part) {
    $reflector = new ReflectionClass($valor);
    $propiedad = $reflector->getProperty($part);
    $propiedad->setAccessible(true);
    $valor = $propiedad->getValue($valor);
}

 return $valor;
}
```

el problema viene con el segundo metodo, el cual necesito acceder al Id de una relación en este caso de la empresa, esta reflexión no me sirve para eso, como podría hacerlo??